# Submitting a dba_job at a clock change

Tags: oracle10g, timezone, oracle9i

A quick query, I'm submitting an oracle job via dbms_job.submit().  However I am in the middle of a clock change BST->GMT and I want my job to execute at 1:30 GMT.  Given that DBA Jobs tends to deal with dates, at what time would my job actually run?

1:30 BST (an hour too early)

or

1:30 GMT (just right thanks)

and if it's the former, is there a way to make it work as I'm expecting?

Thanks

CJC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBMS_JOB doesn't support time zones or daylight savings time for scheduled runs.

The clock change happens at 02h00 when 02h00 becomes 03h00 (but also in this case 02h00 GMT becomes 02h00 BST).  This means your job will run at 01h30 GMT because the clocks won't change until 02h00, however following the daylight saving change (so from the next morning) your job will run at 01h30 BST (00h30 GMT) since DBMS_JOB doesn't know any better, an hour earlier than you might want.

Move to DBA_SCHEDULER instead if you want schedules that always run in GMT or want to have DST support, where the you can specify the time as 01h30 GMT +0 and have it always execute then regardless of anything else.